# Icon not changing in the file location electron

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-packager

I used electron and I made my first calculator app. I packaged the app using ***electron-packager***. So now after doing this I tried to set an icon. However, it is showing in the start menu but not in the file location. Please check the below pics and help me if you can:

Thank you in advance,

[image]

[image]

Comment: try put icon in root project.

Comment: What do u mean?

Comment: Do u mean adding this ```icon: __dirname + 'path/to/icon.png```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar issue, so I put icon in root project. change build script into something like this. It solved the problem.

calculator.png is in root project.

```
"build": {
"nsis": {
  "oneClick": false,
  "perMachine": true,
  "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": true,
  "runAfterFinish": false},
"icon": "calculator.png",
"appId": "calculator"}
```